# MYSQL IF Function

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement, alias

I am using two joins on the same table for two different select statements. I am wanting to implement an IF function, due to the fact that the table may contain a zero, I am wanting to substitue the zero for the word 'None'

Here is my SQL that works:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(`payments`.`AssignedTo`," - ",`people2`.`FName`," ",`people2`.`LName`) AS `AssignedTo`,
CONCAT(`payments`.`PersonID`," - ",`people`.`FName`," ",`people`.`LName`) AS `PersonName`
FROM `mb_payments` as `payments`
LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people` ON `people`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`PersonID`
LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people2` ON `people2`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`AssignedTo`
```

Here is my SQL with the IF function that does not work:

```
SELECT
IF(AssignedTo IS 0,'None', CONCAT(`payments`.`AssignedTo`," - ",`people2`.`FName`," ",`people2`.`LName`)),
CONCAT(`payments`.`PersonID`," - ",`people`.`FName`," ",`people`.`LName`) AS `PersonName`
FROM `mb_payments` as `payments`
LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people` ON `people`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`PersonID`
LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people2` ON `people2`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`AssignedTo`
```

Comment: For more details on how to use a IF statement see here: https://janac.medium.com/if-statements-in-mysql-conditional-logic-7e5acab4e8a8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE statement in this case or if you want to use IF statement then your statement is wrong. 
It should be:

```
SELECT

    IF(AssignedTo = 0,'None', CONCAT(`payments`.`AssignedTo`," - ",`people2`.`FName`," ",`people2`.`LName`)) AS Result,
    CONCAT(`payments`.`PersonID`," - ",`people`.`FName`," ",`people`.`LName`) AS `PersonName`
    FROM `mb_payments` as `payments`
    LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people` ON `people`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`PersonID`
    LEFT JOIN `mb_people` AS `people2` ON `people2`.`PersonID` = `payments`.`AssignedTo`
```

Check out this blog: http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/

Comment: thanks habib, i did not know a case statement could be used such as this.

Comment: @matthewcolley you could use it if you want to, check out the blog link at the end of the answer, it will help you

Answer (score 2):

I think you want ".. = 0", not "... IS 0". You use IS when comparing with NULL.